# How do you fix the discord.js guide embed code error?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to create an embed and I pasted the code straight from the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) right into the code but it's not working and I can't figure out why it's wrong. The code and error are below

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'infotest',
    description: 'infotest',
    execute(message, args) {
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        )
        .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

    channel.send(exampleEmbed);

    },
};
```

```
ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/BotNameHere/Commands/info2.js:5:24)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/BotNameHere/index.js:33:32)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/BotNameHere/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/BotNameHere/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/BotNameHere/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/BotNameHere/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/BotNameHere/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/BotNameHere/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error, you have to define the variable `Discord`.  Just use `require()` to use the `discord.js` module.

Comment: `const Discord = require('discord.js');` is at the top of my main file

Comment: You have to define variables in every file you use them in.  You could either export it to your command handler the same way you export `message` and `args`, or you can just add that line to the top of this file as well

Comment: Happy to be of help!